# Does my set of subtypes have to be complete

Tags: data-modeling

I'm working with a few data modellers developing a logical data model and they are of the opinion that we can have a supertype which has several subtypes but there can be instances of the supertype which are not instances of any of the subtypes.

#### For instance :

Supertype is Insurance Policy, subtypes are Motor Insurance policy and Home Insurance Policy; fine so far; but not all policies are Motor or Home, some are just Insurance Policies.

I would consider that we need to have either:

1. Subtypes for each of the non-motor, non-home policies.

*or*

2. An Other Insurance policy as a subtype.

Of course I am not asking specifically about Insurance but more generally whether the set of subtypes of must be a complete set.

I cannot find anything on this on a web search and its years since I've seen  my data modelling handbook.

Thanks for your answers.

Pat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your supertype is a complete and non-abstract entity, then nothing can be said against creating instances of it. A subtype in this case ist just a specialized entity of the supertype.

And of course you can treat Motor policies as "just" policies, when you do something with them, which can be done with any policy. You don't want to  implement this for any subtype.

You will define a subtype only if it necessary, not just for subtypes to be complete.